# About showing two specific paths in $Z_3* Z_3$ are not equivalent

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, geometric-group-theory

Define $Z_3* Z_3$ to be $\langle a,b\mid a^3,b^3\rangle$. It's easy to see the two paths:

(1) $a \to ab\to aba\to abab \to ababa \to ababab \to \cdots$

and

(2) $a \to aa\to aab\to aaba \to aabaa \to aabaab \to \cdots$

are not equivalent on Cayley graph. But I can't give a strict proof.

My rough idea is to prove there is only one path to connect a vertex on (1), which is after $aa$ and a vertex on (2), which is after $ab$. Otherwise, define such a path as $P$(starting from a vertex $P_1$ after $aa$ on (1) and ending at a vertex $P_2$ after $ab$ on (2): say $P_1\to P_1s_1\to P_1s_1s_2\to \cdots \to P_1 s_1 s_2 \to \cdots \to s_n\to P_2$) , then we can get $P_1s_1s_2\cdots s_n {P_2}^{-1}$ is a loop (relation). However the relations (reduced form) on $\langle a,b \mid a^3, b^3 \rangle$ are generated by $a^3,b^3$, which is a contradiction. So there's only one path. Therefore (1) and (2) are not equivalent.

Can you give me some suggestions on my rough proof, or if you have some other proofs please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: What is "equivalent"? Is it defining the same points on the Gromov boundary?

Comment: @PaulPlummer Two rays are equivalent, if one of the following equivalent conditions hold:
(1) There is a third ray which has infinitely many vertices in common with each.
(2) For every finite vertex set F the two rays are eventually contained in the same connected component of X-F.
(3) There are infinitely many disjoint paths in X joining the two rays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea is that the Cayley graph $\Gamma$ is very similar to a tree $T$ known as the "Bass-Serre tree" of the free product $Z_3 * Z_3$. You can get from $\Gamma$ to $T$ in a two step process. First, replace each vertex of $\Gamma$ by two vertices $v,w \in T$ connected by an edge labelled $e$, where the $a$ and $\bar a$ edges of $\Gamma$ are re-attached to $v$ and the $b$ and $\bar b$ edges are re-attached to $w$; let this intermediate graph be denoted $\Gamma_1$. Second, collapse every $a$ edge and every $b$ edge of $\Gamma_1$ to a point, leaving only the $e$ edges. This tree $T$ has one edge orbit and two vertex orbits. Each vertex in the first vertex orbit is stabilized by a conjugate of the order 3 group $\langle a \rangle$, and each vertex in the second vertex orbit is stablized by a conjugate of the order $3$ group $\langle b \rangle$.

The effect of this construction is to produce two quotient maps, each equivariant under the action of $Z_3 * Z_3$, namely
$$\Gamma \leftarrow \Gamma_1 \rightarrow T
$$
Now take your two rays in $\Gamma$, lift them to $\Gamma_1$, and project them to $T$. You'll obtain two rays in $T$ which go off in different directions almost immediately; and since $T$ is a tree, those rays can never touch again.

And therefore, as you follow each ray out to infinity, its distance to the other ray approaches infinity, so the rays are inequivalent.

Comment: Thank you, I still have questions. First is the quotient map from $\Gamma1$to $\Gamma$ is by shrinking every $e$? Second, why do you need to claim "each equivariant under the action of $Z_3$∗$Z_3$"? Does that imply something? Third, it seems it can deduce that any two paths in $Z_n$*$Z_m$ would not touch again, right?

Comment: Also if in $\Gamma1$ $v_x$ and $v_y$ are connected by a, then after collapsing, are they identified as one vertex?

Comment: First, yes, $\Gamma_1 \to \Gamma$ collapses to a point every edge labelled $e$.

Comment: Second, I always like to remember a central fact of geometric group theory: the Cayley graph of a finitely generated group is that the group acts on the graph, and the action is properly discontinuous and cocompact. The Cayley graph is not the only graph with that property (far from it), and in this example we similarly have actions on $\Gamma_1$ and on $T$.

Comment: Third, the Cayley graph of $Z_3 * Z_3$ is not itself a tree, it has triangles. So it is possible to find a pair of embedded paths which diverge apart and then come together later, the first going along one side of a triangle, the second going along the other two sides, although the two paths (1) and (2) which you constructed do not do this.

Comment: And finally, yes, under a collapse map which identifies an edge to a point, the endpoints of that edge are identified to that point as a consequence.

Comment: Thank you, but for a strict proof,I still you need to ask how do you define "go off in different directions "?

Comment: In any tree, there are no embedded circles. Therefore, if $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ are two embedded paths, then $\gamma_1 \cap \gamma_2$ is a connected subset of both, i.e. a subpath of both. As a corollary, if $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ have the same initial vertex, and if their longest common initial subpaths are $\delta_1,\delta_2$ respectively, then $\gamma_1 - \delta_1$ and $\gamma_2 - \delta_2$ are disjoint.

Comment: Sorry, I feel confused about the result you get. I think you only proved the two rays will not meet again, but it doesn't imply they are not equivalent, right?

Comment: I added a sentence to address your last question.

Comment: Thank you, but if you claim each ray out to infinity, its distance to the other ray approaches infinity, it's equivalent to say there is no path out of the two rays connecting the vertices of the two rays. However, from the proof, we can not get such a claim.

Comment: Can I say if there is a path connecting the two rays after the initial point, name it as b, and name the two end points of b as b1(in the first ray) and b2(in the second ray), then name the part of the first ray(name it as a) from the initial point to b1 as a1, the rest part of the first ray as a2. Similarly by b2 we can divide the second ray as c1 and c2. Now we can construct a third ray by gluing a1,b,c2 and just name it as a1bc2.

Comment: Now consider the relation of a1bc2 and the second ray(name it as c), with the reason from the proof, if b is not in the union of a and c, then a1bc2 and c should not meet. It's a contradiction, so b is contained in the union of a and c. So there is no paths out of a and c which can connect a and c.

Comment: "...it's equivalent to say there is no path out of the two rays connecting the vertices of the two rays". That is not correct. Say the vertices along ray 1, parameterized in order, are $V = \{v_0,v_1,v_2,...\}$ and along ray 2 are $W = \{w_0,w_1,w_2,...\}$. Define $d(v_i,W) = \text{min} \{d(v_i,w_j) \,|\, j \ge 0\}$ and similarly for $d(V,w_j)$. To say that two rays are inequivalent means, **by definition**, that $d(v_i,W) \to +\infty$ as $i \to \infty$, which is equivalent to $d(V,w_j) \to \infty$ as $j \to \infty$.

Comment: sorry for replying so late, i just find your reply. I think "those rays can never touch again" doesn't imply
" follow each ray out to infinity, its distance to the other ray approaches infinity", consider the figure like a ladder which is made of two horizontal lines with connecting edges between the two horizontal lines, the  two horizontal lines don't meet but they are equivalent by definition.

Comment: You have to use the definition of a tree, which I have already laid out previously. A tree contains no ladder-like formations. The path between two points in a tree is *unique* and is there *necessarily the shortest path*, because it is the *only* path.

Comment: But there is no ladder-like formations in the bass-serre tree doesn't mean there is not  no ladder-like formations in the corresponding cayley graph, just like the $a$ and $a^{-1}$ are connected by $a$. Also are $\Gamma$ and $T$ quasi-isometric to each other?

Comment: In a Cayley graph, the oriented edge labelled $a^{-1}$ is the same as the oriented edge labelled $a$ but with opposite orientation.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean we can just consider the distance on Bass-Serre tree instead of the distance on cayley graph to determine the 'inequivalent'? I wonder why we can just consider the distance on Bass-Serre tree?

Comment: Because, by construction of both the Cayley graph and the Bass-Serre tree, there is an equivariant map from the Cayley graph to the Bass-Serre tree that takes shortest paths in the Cayley graph to shortest paths in the Bass-Serre tree. So if two shortest paths in the Cayley graph have inequivalent image in the Bass-Serre tree, then those paths are inequivalent in the Cayley graph.

Comment: Thank you,i think it's true,  is there any reading material to give a rigorous proof showing there is an equivariant map from the Cayley graph to the Bass-Serre tree?

Comment: I don't know of any reading, but the construction is simple. The Cayley graph of $\mathbb{Z}/3 * \mathbb{Z}/3$ is a union of triangles. For each triangle, whose vertices I'll denote $A,B,C$, take a quotient space whose image is a tree having one valence 3 vertex denoted $\Sigma(A,B,C)$ and having three valence 1 vertices at $A,B,C$. This quotient map takes the side $AB$ of the triangle to the path in $\Sigma(A,B,C)$ with endpoints $AB$, and similarly for the other two sides of the triangle. Do this independently for each triangle of the Cayley graph, and you'll get the Bass-Serre tree.